# Difference between O(log n) and O(log(n + a))

Tags: algorithm

I'm working through a homework problem on simplifying a recurrence and trying to find the upper bound.

I've got my equation down to `O(log(n + 2))`, and was wondering if, in general:

`O(log(n)) = O(log(n + a))` for any `a`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can say that if `a` is completely independent of input size. The motive is to show how the complexity increases/decreases with respect to the size of input data.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if a function `f` is known to be `O(log n)` then it's also `O(log(n + a))` for any constant `a`.

To see that we calculate the limit

```
lim log(n + a) / log(n) =
  = lim log(n (1 + a/n)) / log(n) =
  = lim (log(n) + log(1 + a/n)) / log(n) =
  = lim 1 + (log(1 + a/n)/log(n)) =
  = 1
```

as n goes to infinity. Next since `f` is `O(log n)`, using the [`lim sup` definition of the Big O notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) we have:

```
C = lim sup f(n) / log(n) =
  = lim sup f(n) / log(n + a) * log(n + a) / log(n) =
  = (lim sup f(n) / log(n + a)) * 1
```

Therefore `lim sup f(n) / log(n + a)` is also bounded by `C` and, accordingly, `f` is `O(log(n + a))`.